# Anomalous behaviour of ADC, digitalWrite and floating point operations

Tags: arduino-uno, adc, float

I'm trying to analyse mic (A0) input, calculate certain spectral lines with Goertzel algorithm to detect a number encoded by DTFM and display it with 8x8 matrix display (max7219 driver).

The code works perfectly fine without a display sending the result to serial, however when I added a display, strange things started to happen.

- if `goertzel(..)` is called before `displayDigit` the display doesn't show anything
- if `displayDigit` is called first the output of `goertzel(..)` is a complete mess
- if I comment out 1 line in `goertzel(..)` which is `amp = sqrt(re * re + im * im); // [1]` the display works (but it doesn't make sense)

I'm using Arduino UNO, ADC in free-run mode.

The code below:

```
/**
 * 8x8 LED matrix display with MAX7219 driver
 * +5V, GND, CLK (8 pin), CS (9 pin), DIN (10 pin)
 */
#include <binary.h> 
#include <LedControl.h>

#include "font8x8.h"

#define N           256
#define IX_LEN      8
#define THRESHOLD   20

/* Display PINs */
#define CLK     13//8
#define CS      12 //9
#define DIN     8 //10

LedControl matrix = LedControl(DIN, CLK, CS, 1);
int8_t lastDetectedDigit = -1;
int8_t currentDigit = -1;
uint32_t lastDetectedMillis = 0;

const int adc_channel = 0;

volatile uint16_t samples[N];
volatile uint16_t samplePos = 0;

float spectrum[IX_LEN] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

// Frequences [697.0, 770.0, 852.0, 941.0, 1209.0, 1336.0, 1477.0, 1633.0]
// Corresponding spectrum indexes [18, 20, 22, 25, 32, 35, 39, 43]

// Calculated for 9615Hz 256 samples  
const float cos_t[IX_LEN] = {
  0.9039892931234433, 0.881921264348355, 0.8577286100002721, 0.8175848131515837, 
  0.7071067811865476, 0.6531728429537769, 0.5758081914178454, 0.49289819222978415
  };

const float sin_t[IX_LEN] = {
  0.4275550934302821, 0.47139673682599764, 0.5141027441932217, 0.5758081914178453, 
  0.7071067811865475, 0.7572088465064845, 0.8175848131515837, 0.8700869911087113  
  };

const char table[4][4] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

const uint8_t char_indexes[4][4] = {
  {0, 1, 2, 12},
  {3, 4, 5, 13},
  {6, 7, 8, 14},
  {10, 9, 11, 15}
};


void initADC() {
  // Init ADC; f = ( 16MHz/prescaler ) / 13 cycles/conversion 
  ADMUX  = adc_channel; // Channel sel, right-adj, use AREF pin
  ADCSRA = _BV(ADEN)  | // ADC enable
           _BV(ADSC)  | // ADC start
           _BV(ADATE) | // Auto trigger
           _BV(ADIE)  | // Interrupt enable
           _BV(ADPS2) | _BV(ADPS1) | _BV(ADPS0); // 128:1 / 13 = 9615 Hz
//  ADCSRB = _BV(ADTS2) | _BV(ADTS0);              // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
  ADCSRB = 0; // Free-run mode
  DIDR0  = _BV(adc_channel); // Turn off digital input for ADC pin      
}

void goertzel(volatile uint16_t *samples, float *spectrum) {
  float v[N + 2];
  float re, im, amp;

  for (uint8_t k = 0; k < IX_LEN; k++) {
    float a = 2. * cos_t[k];
    v[0] = v[1] = .0;    
    for (uint16_t i = 2; i < N + 2; i++) {
      v[i] = float(samples[i - 2]) + a * v[i - 1] - v[i - 2];      
    }
    re = cos_t[k] * v[N + 1] - v[N];
    im = sin_t[k] * v[N + 1];
    amp = sqrt(re * re + im * im); // [1]
    spectrum[k] = amp;        
  } 
}

float avg(float *a, uint16_t len) {
  float result = .0;
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result += a[i];
  }
  return result / len;
}

int8_t get_single_index_above_threshold(float *a, uint16_t len, float threshold) {

  if (threshold < THRESHOLD) {
    return -1;
  }

  int8_t ix = -1;
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] > threshold) {
      if (ix == -1) {
        ix = i;
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    } 
  }
  return ix;  
}

char detect_digit(float *spectrum) {
  float avg_row = avg(spectrum, 4);
  float avg_col = avg(&spectrum[4], 4);
  int8_t row = get_single_index_above_threshold(spectrum, 4, avg_row);
  int8_t col = get_single_index_above_threshold(&spectrum[4], 4, avg_col);

  if (row != -1 && col != -1) {
    return table[row][col];
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void displayDigit(uint8_t c) {
  if (currentDigit == c) {
    return;
  }

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    matrix.setColumn(0, 7 - i, IMAGES[c][i]); 
  }
  currentDigit = c;
}

void setup() {  
  cli();
  initADC();
  sei();

  matrix.shutdown(0, false);
  matrix.setIntensity(0, 2);

  Serial.begin(115200);

}

unsigned long z = 0;

void loop() {
  while(ADCSRA & _BV(ADIE)); // Wait for audio sampling to finish

  goertzel(samples, spectrum);   
  samplePos = 0;

//  if (z % 25 == 0) {
    displayDigit(2); 

    for (int i = 0; i < IX_LEN; i++) {
      Serial.print(spectrum[i]);
      Serial.print("\t");
    }
    Serial.println();
    char digit = detect_digit(spectrum);
    Serial.println(digit);
//  }
  z++;



  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADIE);       // Resume sampling interrupt
}

ISR(ADC_vect) { 
  uint16_t sample = ADC;

  samples[samplePos++] = sample;

  if(samplePos >= N) {
    ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADIE); // Buffer full, interrupt off
  }
}
```

`font8x8.h`:

```
const byte IMAGES[16][8] = {
{
  B00001000,
  B00011000,
  B00001000,
  B00001000,
  B00001000,
  B00001000,
  B00001000,
  B00011100
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00000100,
  B00011000,
  B00100000,
  B01000000,
  B01111110
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B00000010,
  B00000100,
  B00000100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00010100,
  B00100100,
  B00100100,
  B01000100,
  B01111110,
  B00000100,
  B00000100,
  B00000100
},{
  B00111110,
  B01000000,
  B01000000,
  B01111100,
  B00000010,
  B00000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000000,
  B01111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00111110,
  B01000010,
  B00000100,
  B00000100,
  B00001000,
  B00001000,
  B00010000,
  B00010000
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111110,
  B00000010,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000110,
  B01001010,
  B01010010,
  B01010010,
  B01010010,
  B01100010,
  B00111100
},{
  B00000000,
  B01010100,
  B00111000,
  B01111100,
  B00111000,
  B01010100,
  B00000000,
  B00000000
},{
  B00101000,
  B00101000,
  B11111110,
  B00101000,
  B11111110,
  B00101000,
  B00101000,
  B00000000
},{
  B00011100,
  B00100010,
  B00100010,
  B01000010,
  B01111110,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010
},{
  B01111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01111100
},{
  B00111100,
  B01000010,
  B01000000,
  B01000000,
  B01000000,
  B01000000,
  B01000010,
  B00111100
},{
  B01111000,
  B01000100,
  B01000110,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01111100
}};
```

I use `LedControl.h` library but inside is uses only digitalWrite, no timing, interrupts.

Can somebody explain what is the problem?

**UPD**
This is what IDE tells me about the sizes:

```
Sketch uses 5602 bytes (17%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1048 bytes (51%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1000 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

[This is LedControl library I'm using](https://github.com/wayoda/LedControl)

Comment: Please update your question with more information. Can you give a link to the LedControl library and tell us what the compiler says about flash and ram usage. Start looking for an other arduino board, for example an arduino mkr or a arduino compatible board with a esp8266 or esp32.

Comment: How much static RAM does your program use, according to the compiler? Seems to me that should be close to 1 K, leaving little more than 1 K for the stack. Your `goertzel()` function alone uses more than 1 K of stack, so you could well be smashing the stack against the BSS.

Comment: Thx, @EdgarBonet I haven't even though about these constraints. I'll try to move constants to flash memory and replace floats to fixed point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your recent edit:

> Global variables use 1048 bytes (51%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1000
>   bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Your `goertzel()` function defines this

```
float v[N + 2];
```

where `N` is 256. This alone takes 258×4 = 1032 bytes of
stack and you only have 1000 bytes available. Then, as I suspected,
you are smashing the stack against the [.bss section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss), effectively
overwriting some of your global variables with the local ones.

It is hard to predict what can happen in such circumstances. The program
is corrupting its memory: you can only expect it to act erratically.